# Rename multiple files from command line

Tags: perl, bash, rename, file-rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Renaming lots of files in Linux according to a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316600/renaming-lots-of-files-in-linux-according-to-a-pattern)

I have multiple files in this format:

```
file_1.pdf
file_2.pdf
...
file_100.pdf
```

My question is how can I rename all files, that look like this:

```
file_001.pdf
file_002.pdf
...
file_100.pdf
```

I know you can rename multiple files with 'rename', but I don't know how to do this in this case.

Comment: http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-unix.html

Comment: https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/prename

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this using the Perl tool [`rename`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?rename) from the `shell` prompt. (There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.)

```
rename 's/(\d+)/sprintf("%03d", $1)/e' *.pdf
```

If you want to do a dry run to make sure you don't clobber any files, add the `-n` switch to the command.

### note

If you run the following command (`linux`)

```
$ file $(readlink -f $(type -p rename))
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

This seems to be the default `rename` command on `Ubuntu`.

To make it the default on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

### Explanations

- `s///` is the base substitution expression : `s/to_replace/replaced/`, check `perldoc perlre`
- `(\d+)` capture with `()` at least one integer : `\d` or more : `+` in `$1`
- `sprintf("%03d", $1)` `sprintf` is like `printf`, but not used to *print* but to *format* a string with the same syntax. `%03d` is for zero padding, and `$1` is the captured string. Check `perldoc -f sprintf`
- the later *perl's function* is permited because of the `e` modifier at the end of the *expression*

Comment: This does not seem to make any sense. How is this connected to Perl? Standard Linux `rename` does not have `-n` and does not support advanced replacement sed-style. Perl `rename` is very simple and cannot do this by default either. What is this? Please give more thorough example.

Comment: [`rename`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?rename) on CPAN does have `-n`.

Comment: If you have a `ELF` binary instead of `Perl`, this is another tool, nothing to do with the explained one.

Comment: I have no experience in Perl, but [I know regular expressions](https://xkcd.com/208/). Would you mind updating this to briefly explain its usage more broadly? I was personally able to remove the `.txt` file extension from some files with `rename s/(.*).txt/sprintf($1)/e' *.txt` but I do not fully understand how it worked. What is the `s` at the beginning and the `/e` at the end, and why is the print statement immediately after the regular expression?

Comment: Added explanations

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with pure bash:

```
for f in file_*.pdf; do x="${f##*_}"; echo mv "$f" "${f%_*}$(printf '_%03d.pdf' "${x%.pdf}")"; done
```

(note the debugging **echo**)