# AWK, SED, REGEX to rename files

Tags: regex, sed, awk, filenames, renaming

I'm only learning to use REGEX, AWK and SED. I currently have a group of files that I'd like to rename - they all sit in one directory.

The naming pattern is consistent, but I would like to re-arrange the filenames, here is the format:

```
01._HORRIBLE_HISTORIES_S2.mp4
02._HORRIBLE_HISTORIES_S2.mp4
```

I'd like to rename them to HORRIBLE_HISTORIES_s01e01.mp4 - where the e01 is gleaned from the first column.  I know that I want to grab "01" from the first column, stuff it in a variable then paste it after the S2 in each filename, at the same time I want to remove it from the beginning of the filename along with the "._", additionally I want to change the "S2" to "s02".

If anyone would be so kind, could you help me write something using awk/sed and explain the procedure, that I might learn from it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
for f in *.mp4; do 
  echo mv "$f" \
    "$(awk -F '[._]' '{ si = sprintf("%02s", substr($5,2)); 
                          print $3 "_" $4 "_s" si "e" $1 "." $6 }' <<<"$f")"
done
```

- Loops over all `*.mp4` files.
- Renames each to the result of the `awk` command, provided via command substitution (`$(...)`).
- The `awk` command splits the input filename into tokens by `.` or "_" (which makes the first token available as `$1`, the second as `$2`, ...).
- First, the number in "_S{number}" is left-padded to 2 digits with a `0` (i.e., a `0` is only prepended if the number doesn't already have 2 digits) and stored in variable `si` (season index); if it's OK to always prepend `0`, the awk "program" can be simplified to: `{ print $3 "_" $4 "_s0" substr($5,2) "e" $1 "." $6 }`
- The result, along with the remaining tokens, is then rearranged to form the desired filename.

Note the `echo` before `mv` to allow you to safely preview the resulting command - remove it to perform actual renaming.

**Alternative**: a pure `bash` solution using a regular expression:

```
for f in *.mp4; do 
  [[ $f =~ ^([0-9]+)\._([^.]+)_S([^.]+)\.(.+)$ ]]
  echo mv "$f" \
"${BASH_REMATCH[2]}_s0${BASH_REMATCH[3]}e${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
done
```

- Uses bash's regular-expression matching operator, `=~`, with capture groups (the substrings in `(...)`) to match against each filename and extract substrings of interest.
- The matching results are stored in the special array variable `$BASH_REMATCH`, with element `0` containing the entire match, `1` containing what matches the first capture group, `2` the second, and so on.
- The `mv` command's target argument then assembles the capture-group matches in the desired order; note that in this case, for simplicity, I've made the zero-padding of `s{number}` unconditional - a `0` is simply prepended.

As above, you need to remove `echo` before `mv` to perform actual renaming.

Answer (score 10):

A common way of renaming multiple files according to a pattern, is to use the Perl command [`rename`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?rename). It uses Perl regular expressions and is very powerful. Use `-n -v` to test the pattern without touching the files:

```
$ rename -n -v 's/^(\d+)._(.+)_S2\.mp4/$2_s02e$1.mp4/' *.mp4
01._HORRIBLE_HISTORIES_S2.mp4 renamed as HORRIBLE_HISTORIES_s02e01.mp4
02._HORRIBLE_HISTORIES_S2.mp4 renamed as HORRIBLE_HISTORIES_s02e02.mp4
```

Use parentheses to capture strings into variables `$1` (first capture), `$2` (second capture) etc:

- `^(\d+)` capture numbers at beginning of filename (into `$1)`
- `._(.+)_S2\.mp4` capture everything between `._` and `_S2.mp4` (into `$2`)
- `$2_s02e$1.mp4` assemble your new filename with the captured data as you want it

When you are happy with the result, remove `-n` from the command and it will rename all the files for real.

`rename` is often available by default on Linux (package `util-linux`). There is a [similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14327650/2061321) here on SO with more details about finding/installing the right command.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with almost pure `bash` (with [variable expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)):

```
for f in *mp4 ; do
  newfilename="${f:5:20}_s01e${f:1:2}.mp4"
  echo mv $f $newfilename
done
```

If the output from this command suits your needs, you may remove the `echo` from the cycle, or more simply (if your last command was the above) issue: `!! | bash`

Comment: I assume this is only good for fixed sized strings. How would you replace an extension with another on arbitrary sizes?

Answer (score 2):

using AWK. rename file with first and second and 4th part

```
ls | while read file; do newfile=`echo $file | awk -F . '{print $1 "." $2 "." $4}'`; echo $newfile;  mv $file $newfile; done;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the filename string into a textfile then use loop and awk to rename file.

```
while read oldname; do
  newname=$(awk -F'.' '{ print substr($2, 2) "_e" $1 "." $3 }' <<< ${oldname} | \
        awk -F'_' '{ print $1 "_s0" substr($2, 2) $3 }');
  mv ${oldname} ${newname};
done<input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use `gawk`, the regex matching really comes in handy. I find this pipe-based solution a little nicer than worrying about looping constructs.

```
ls -1 | \
    gawk 'match($0, /.../, a) { printf ... | "sh" } \
    END { close("sh") }'
```

For ease of reading I've replaced the regex and the `mv` command with ellipses.

- Line 1 lists all the file names in the current directory, one line each and pipes that to the gawk command.
- Line 2 runs the regex match, assigning captured groups to the array variable `a`. The action converts this into our desired command with `printf` which is itself piped to `sh` to execute.
- Line 3 closes the shell that was implicitly opened when we started piping things to it.

So then you just fill in your regex and command syntax (borrowing from [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21361414/9304)). For example (**LIVE CODE WARNING**):

```
ls -1 | \
    gawk 'match($0, /^([0-9]+)\._([^.]+)_S([^.]+)\.(.+)$/, a) { printf "mv %s %s_s0%se%s.%s\n",a[0],a[2],a[3],a[1],a[4] | "sh" } \
    END { close("sh") }'
```

To preview that command (as you should) you can simply remove the `| "sh"` from the second line.