# Trim file names to initials, swap fields and pad numbers with Awk

Tags: awk

Trying to run these operations in a bunch of files:

```
 1. Swap field position and pad numbers if necessary
 2. Trim file name fields to initials
 3. Adjust -
```

a minimal example would be something like;

from this:

```
01 - Some - Else - Edu.txt
02 - Some thing - Else where - Edu.txt
3 - SOME THING - ELSE WHERE - Edu.txt
```

to this:

```
S-E - 01 - Edu.txt
St-Ew - 02 - Edu.txt
ST-EW - 03 - Edu.txt
```

How can I do it with (g)awk (or in conjunction with other tools, if needed) ??

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, thank you

Comment: `perl -e 'for(@ARGV){($n,$m,$s)=/^(\d+) +- +(.*)(- .*)$/ or next; $m=~s/(.).*? +/$1/g; rename$_,sprintf"$m - %02d $s",$n}' *.txt`

Comment: @jhnc Thank you sir, was trying to do something with perl's rename aswell, but my inability to properly understand the docs capped my efforts greatly, also I'm sick of reading basic examples that take me nowhere.

Comment: m// above can accept invalid input. regexp should be `/^(\d+) +- +(.* )(- .*)$/` (ie. add explicit space after first `.*`). This avoids mangled output if the subsequent s/// doesn't see a trailing space. eg: `01 - Some - Else- Edu.txt` should be ignored but with original regexp would become `S-Else - 01 - Edu.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `tst.awk` file:

```
$ cat tst.awk 
    {if(NF=="7") printf "%s-%s - %02d - %s\n", substr($3,1,1), substr($5,1,1), $1, $7
     if(NF=="9") printf "%s%s-%s%s - %02d - %s\n", substr($3,1,1), substr($4,1,1), substr($6,1,1), substr($7,1,1), $1, $9}
```

**bash one-liner**

```
$ for file in *Edu.txt ; do newfilename=`awk -f tst.awk <<<"$file"`; echo mv "$file" "$newfilename"; done
```

- Note that `echo` before `mv` is to safely preview resulting command. Remove `echo` to run actual `mv` command.
- `awk.tst` is created to keep terminal screen clean and for later modifications. so in terminal you only run `awk.tst` file in `one-liner` instead of whole `awk` code
- This works with the given sample file pattern. If there are any file that contains more than two words between `-` then simply add `if` condition line in `awk` file as `NF=="#"` whereas `#` is number of words between each space and edit `printf` formatting accordingly.

Below is the list of what was there in current working directory **before**:

```
$ find .
.
./tst.awk
./01 - Some - Else - Edu.txt
./02 - Some thing - Else where - Edu.txt
./3 - SOME THING - ELSE WHERE - Edu.txt
```

**Resulting Output**

```
$ find .
.
./tst.awk
./S-E - 01 - Edu.txt
./St-Ew - 02 - Edu.txt
./ST-EW - 03 - Edu.txt
```

also see here for other methods [AWK, SED, REGEX to rename files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21359567/14320738)

Comment: Looks great, can you explain how to use it directly into the files, instead of an input file?

Comment: do you mean like "applying to files under a directory instead of one file" or "apply to matching specific lines in a file" please add more detail and share some samples for better understanding.

Comment: @AhmetSaidAkbulut "applying to files under a directory instead of one file" exactly that

Comment: @RenatoD.O. does this answer your question?

Comment: Got a syntax error at line 1 (unexpected token next to {if(NF=="7")) but I did accepted the answer.

Comment: Thank you but I try to figure out and works perfectly fine for me. you may try this out as it is a plain one-liner without tst.awk `for file in *Edu.txt ; do newfilename=$(awk '{if(NF=="7") printf "%s-%s - %02d - %s\n", substr($3,1,1), substr($5,1,1), $1, $7; if(NF=="9") printf "%s%s-%s%s - %02d - %s\n", substr($3,1,1), substr($4,1,1), substr($6,1,1), substr($7,1,1), $1, $9}' <<<"$file"); echo mv "$file" "$newfilename"; done`

Comment: Very interesting though... above tested code in the comment may be more consistent for you. Apart from that, I run out of ideas...