# How to rename all the files in current directory in linux

Tags: linux

I want to rename all the files in the current directory. So right now they are of the form: "xxx-9666_01.so", I want to rename it to "xxx_9444_01.so". How do I do it in Linux?

Comment: You should explain the kind of change you want in the filenames, eg do you actually just want `9666` to become `9444` if encountered in a file name? I don't think that that's what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renaming lots of files in Linux according to a pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316600/renaming-lots-of-files-in-linux-according-to-a-pattern)

Comment: @fvu yes just that

Comment: Try `rename '9666' '9444' ???_9666_01.so`.

Comment: The problem with `rename` is there are multiple `rename` executables with wildly different options. The standard `rename` installed by most distros from the `util-linux` package (from kernel.org), and the other (I believe perl `rename`).

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop:

```
for f in *-9666_01.so; do
  echo mv "$f" "${f%-9666_01.so}_9444_01.so"
done
```

Remove the `echo` when you're sure it's doing what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the previous answer using *parameter expansion* with *substring replacement* (as opposed to *substring removal*) can accomplish the same goal, and may be a bit more readable:

```
for f in *-9666_01.so; do
    echo mv "$f" "${f/-9666/-9444}"
done
```

(remove `echo` when you are satisfied with the operation)

(where the *substring replacement* will replace `a` with `b` in `f` using the form `${f/a/b}` (the closing `/` is implied) to replace the *first* instance of `a` with `b`, or `${f//a/b}` to replace *all* instances of `a` with `b`)